# Serializable class attribute in FSharp

Tags: serialization, f#

I have a class developed in F# that must be serializable. How can I set it as serializable? Like [Serializable] in c# using class attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[<Serializable>]` in the same way that you'd use C#'s `[Serializable]`.